# Can't present full JSON (ng-repeat) AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-repeat

Try to present all data with ng-repeat from web service.
This is my controller JS (GetAllCtrl.js):
[image]

I get JSON data:
[image]

Now I want to get only company data without *coupons* data
(Company structure in JSON is: compName, id, email, *coupons*[]) 
In GetAllCtrl.js I have put the data in *allComp* variable.

This is GetAllCtrl.html:
[image]

I do ng-repeat in **tr** tag and use *$index* for loop on the array with data.
But in output, I get only 2 companies instead 4.
In clonsole.log I see 4 objects.[image]

I'm new in AngularJS and JS and can't understand why it happened.

Comment: You are iterating in ng-repeat over the wrong variable. It should be ng-repeat="c in getAllCtrl.allComp"

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over the wrong variable. It should be  `ng-repeat="c in getAllCtrl.allComp.data"` and correspondingly change your td elements.

```
<tr ng-repeat="c in getAllCtrl.allComp.data track by $index">
 <td align="center"><b>c.compName</b></td>
 <td align="center"><b>c.id</b></td>
 <td align="center"><b>c.email</b></td>
</tr>
```